# Can I add type information to arguments that are functions in Julia?

Tags: julia

Can I add type information to arguments that are functions?

Consider the following example:

```
function f{T} (func, x::Int)
    output = Dict{Int, Any}()
    output[x] = func(x)
    return output
end
```

I don't like that I have to say `Any` for the value type of the dictionary.  I'd much rather do the following:

```
function f{T} (func::Function{Int->T}, x::Int)
    output = Dict{Int, T}()
    output[x] = func(x)
    return output
end
```

Can I provide type hints of functions like this?  I kind of want to say the following

```
f :: (Int -> T), Int -> Dict{Int, T}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not currently. We may add something along those lines in the future, however.

Comment: Any chance of Haskell-like all-in-one type declarations too? (like the bottom line of the question)

Comment: There is some chance.

Comment: Has this changed with 0.5? We can now do `function hello(x::String)::String "Hello, "*x*"!" end` for named functions...can we do anything along the lines of `x::Function{ _ -> String}; x = hello`? (Incidentally, in the example above, `hello::Function` passes, `typeof(hello)` is `#hello`, and `Base.return_types(hello)` is `1-element Array{Any,1}: String`.)

Comment: Not really. You can add a return type to a method but the type of the function itself still doesn't include arity or argument types or return type.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the main question, but more a **really ugly** workaround the `Any` in the `Dict` issue:

```py
function f(func, x::Int)
    T = code_typed(func, (Int,))[1].args[3].typ
    output = Dict{Int, T}()
    output[x] = func(x)
    return output
end
```

That is probably not efficient and will probably work only on simple cases (which do not even include anonymous functions) like

```py
>>> g(x) = x*2
>>> typeof(f(g, 1234))
Dict{Int64,Int64}

>>> h(x) = x > zero(x) ? x : nothing
>>> typeof(f(h, 1234))
Dict{Int64,Union(Int64,Nothing)}
```

**EDIT:**

This works better:

```py
function f(func, x::Int)
    [x => func(x)]
end

>>> dump( f(x->2x, 3) )
Dict{Int64,Int64} len 1
    3: Int64 6
```