# How do I grow a Julia array in a type-respecting way?

Tags: types, julia

I'm writing a function that searches through a collection and collects the outputs of some user-supplied functions `f` and `g` applied to things it finds.

```
function search_map_collect(f::Function, g::Function)
  output = []
  # searching through the collection
    # oh look we found an x and a y
      push!(output, f(x, y))
    # whoa, we even found a z
      push!(output, g(x, y, z))
  # end loopy stuff
  return output
end
```

As the function is written, the output will always have type `Array{Any,1}`, because that's the type of the empty array. However, it will often be the case that `f` and `g` always return values of the same type `T`. In this case, a built-in function like `map` would return an output of type `Array{T,1}`, and I'd like my function to behave the same. Is there a nice way to do this?

---

If Julia supported function types with [signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21053491/1644283), this would be easy. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

---

If I could easily predict when `f` or `g` would first be applied, I could initialize the output array as

```
  output = [f(x_first, y_first)]
```

to set the type. Unfortunately, I can't predict the first application.

---

I realize I could do something horrific like

```
function complicated_collect(f::Function, g::Function)
  output = Union{}[]
  # searching through the collection
    # oh look we found an x and a y
      if isempty(output)
        output = [f(x, y)]
      else
        push!(output, f(x, y))
      end
    # whoa, we even found a z
      if isempty(output)
        output = [g(x, y, z)]
      else
        push!(output, g(x, y, z))
      end
  # end loopy stuff
  return output
end
```

but this makes the code much less readable, and it doesn't feel very efficient either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the return type when you call the function,
you can add it as an argument.

```
function test1(t::Type, f::Function)
  output = t[]
  for x in 1:5
    push!( output, f(x) )
  end
  output  
end
test1( Float64, exp )
@code_warntype test1(exp)
```

Since it is type-stable, it should be more efficient
than using the type of the first element found.

Comment: This is the workaround I'm currently using. I think it's pretty ugly, but if it's the only way, then it's the only way. Thank you for pointing out the advantage of type-stability—it's not something I'd thought about before.